# Pie chart background changes when slice too small in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

Please help me out from this problem in pie-chart using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

**This is a library bug.**

When I have a pie slice that is too small, the color for that slice bleeds into the chart background. Like in the pictures below - you can see the yellow color has bled.

[image: a pie chart where the small pie slice background has bled into the view background]

I'm setting static float data in `setData()`:-

```
private void setData(int count, float range) {
     yVals1.add(new Entry(100.9f, 0));
     yVals1.add(new Entry(0.01f, 1));
}
```

It means when we enter a huge difference between 2 values then this problem will arise. Please help me out.

Comment: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1699 I guess this is the same issue reported on their Github. I will suggest either wait for their reply, or you can edit the library yourself and fix the bug. In case you fix it, you can also post solution there to help others :)