# How to hide line also with slice text hide in mp chart android?

Tags: android, charts, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

[image]

I hide slice text when values are 0, but I cannot remove these lines...
How can we remove it when chart slice value

Comment: Please check this hope this helps you. :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325659/pie-chart-background-changes-when-slice-too-small-in-mpandroidchart

Comment: Post your code for showing this chart, with xml. Also, what you tried and not work removing this lines

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use this following code:

```
pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(0)
```